# Device independent pixels vs Scale independent pixels

Tags: android, dpi

I know this question has been discussed over and over, but I still get confused with an answer to a very [popular question in stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26425363/438044).

[image]

More specifically this example.

Simple question.
Shouldn't the text in DP and SP look the same on all screens ? They both have ~160 physical units per inch. My only assumption is the text referenced to 30sp is dependent of another factor.

Comment: Simple answer. **sp != dp**

Comment: an explanation as to why would be appreciated, but thanks for the input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily, DP is independent of a user's font settings whereas SP retains it. If a user has their settings so that the font on their device is enlarged (for accessibility reasons for example), SP will take that into account, whereas DP will not.